# Find best repartition of choices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several people making *x* choices ranked in order of preference among *n* possibilities. Each possibility can only be assigned once.

I would like to find all the solutions to the problem such that each person has a choice of a minimum level *xmin*.

For example, for `x=3` and say `n=20`, and 10 peoples making choices :

```py
    g1 = (3, 10, 11)  # g1 makes choices 3, 10 and 11 in order of preference
    g2 = (10, 9, 5)
    g3 = (10, 15, 3)
    g4 = (5, 9, 14)
    g5 = (10, 3, 7)
    ...
    g10 = (4, 19, 2)
```

With Python, how to write the problem to find the solutions so that all people have a choice with at least level 2 (`xmin=2`) assigned ? then level 3 (`xmin=3`) if there is no solution for `xmin=2` ?

I think there is something to do with `itertools`, but I can't get a clear idea about this problem.

**EDIT**: Thinking a little bit more about the problem, I have something like this coming to me:

```py
import itertools

xmin = 2

groups = [g1, g2, g3, g4, g5]
sample = [g[:xmin] for g in groups]

[seq for seq in itertools.product(*sample) if len(seq) == len(set(seq))]
```

I wasn't awake, the answer is simple in fact!

Comment: Did you try to write any code part to solve this problem? even the most direct

Comment: No, I have no idea how to start the code. In fact, every year I find myself confronted with the same problem and I solve it "by hand". But I was thinking that a script could save me a lot of time. 
In fact, what I really need is not the code, but the mathematical logic to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: I see your edit. Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, `itertools` simplifies life as always :)

With this dataset :

```py
gr1 = (3, 10, 11)
gr2 = (10, 9, 5)
gr3 = (10, 15, 3)
gr4 = (5, 9, 14)
gr5 = (10, 22, 7)
gr6 = (24, 9, 17)
gr7 = (10, 17, 3)
gr8 = (14, 21, 2)
gr9 = (14, 12, 21)
gr10 = (9, 1, 22)
gr11 = (19, 2, 8)
gr12 = (3, 8, 24)
gr13 = (9, 5, 13)
gr14 = (9, 1, 12)
```

Here is a solution to the problem:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

xmin = 3
groups = [gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4, gr5, gr6, gr7, gr8, gr9, gr10, gr11, gr12, gr13, gr14]


sample = [g[:xmin] for g in groups]
assign = [seq for seq in itertools.product(*sample) if len(seq) == len(set(seq))]
choices = [[sample[i].index(assign[j][i]) for i in range(len(sample))] for j in range(len(assign))]

print(f'{len(choices)} possibilities found')

pertinence = [sum(choices[i]) for i in range(len(choices))]
best = np.array(assign)[np.array(pertinence) == min(pertinence)]

print(f'{len(best)} best choices:')
print(best)
```

If someone has a more elegant solution...